# Running TensorFlow Extended (TFX) on AWS

Tags: tensorflow, apache-beam, tfx

I was wondering if it is possible/how easy it would be to implement a TFX pipeline (on a real dataset, with 100+ GB dataset, not a tutorial with a small dataset) in AWS?

For the orchestration, I might use Kubeflow. But I suppose, the major issue would be setting up a proper scalable runner for the Apache Beam. I am thinking of using Apache Flink for that.

Anyone with experience doing it? How would you go about putting a TF in production in AWS in general when you need to train the model on a regular basis on new data, do you write the pipeline from scratch or use some tool?

Comment: Did you solve this problem? How did you resolve this issue? Please share some deatils.

Comment: I'm trying to solve a similar issue, and am hoping with Kubeflow now being version 2, that this becomes solvable.  I know the LocalDagRunner is limited to the amount of memory in the machine, so I'm also investigating Kubeflow.  The issue of shared storage needs to be solved, which I guess something like minio can help with.  I know tfx has a cli for generating templates, however I just re-use something across projects that has all the components and just write preprocessing_fn, model.py and tuner.py depending on the nature of the problem.